# Ruby on Rails - Display syntax error from 500 internal server error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, syntax, internal-server-error

How can I get the error which causes the 500 internal server error? Nothing is in the log file, unfortunately I did not write the code, I am just in charge of maintaining it and the code is quite a mess / all over the place.

All I get is:

```
We're sorry, but something went wrong.

We've been notified about this issue and we'll take a look at it shortly.
```

But that does not help me identify the line of code causing the issue.

Comment: check your Rails server logs, not just the web server logs. They'll be in `logs/production.log`.

Comment: This may help  [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21963344/why-am-i-getting-error-500-were-sorry-but-something-went-wrong-when-pushing-m]

Comment: You need to check your production log for the issue. Also, the may have handled the error in application controller which handles any error across the site, you may inspect that which should help.

Comment: Also, use a tool like Airbrake (http://airbrake.io) which will catch and report any errors that your application raises.